# Why EC2 instance is stopping again and again?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I can't keep my EC2 instance in running state. Whenever I start the instance it always changing back to "Stopped" state. I tried many ways like they mentioned in this official page [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesStopping.html).

1. Stopped and restarted the instance - didn't work
2. Created an alternate image of the current instance and launched a new instance with that image and started it. - didn't work
3. Finally, made a snapshot of current volume of stopped instance. Then created anew volume with that snapshot. Launched a new instance with a new AMI and stopped it. Then detached the root volume of new instance and attached the newly created volume as root volume. Then started the instance - didn't work though.

UPDATE: when I run below command to check the reason for the issue

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id MYINSTANCE --output json
```

it response with below issue

```
"StateReason": {
                    "Code": "Client.InstanceInitiatedShutdown",
                    "Message": "Client.InstanceInitiatedShutdown: Instance initiated shutdown"
                },
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are your volumes/AMI encrypted? Do you have permissions over the encryption key?

Comment: not encrypted..

Comment: Are you using some sort of startup script?

Comment: not really. We use it to run a python script later after instance is running

Comment: Something initiated the shutdown. You may check the CloudTrail if the instace is stopped using the aws api call (some organization have policies to shut down instances without correct tagging), or some code/script from within the server (maybe found in the system logs?) . Without more information it would be a wild guess

Comment: It sounds like a script or cron job on the instance itself is telling the operating system to shutdown.

Comment: There is no cron job. If it is the case, why a newly launched instance (with attached volume) behave the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

- Create another fresh instance and ensure its working fine
- Remove storage from this instance and attach it to the affected instance
- Start your affected instance now which is having new latest storage (make sure to remove old storage)

If it works then it means there is some issue in the storage drive only.

---

If the above does not work then there is also possible some hardware issue. you can try creating same instance in different region with the same image to see if it works in different region or not.